# Не выводятся данные при пост запросе, используется ksoap2 android

Tags: java, android

Не получается вывести расписание занятий в `TextView`. Используется библиотека `ksoap2`. При передаче параметров potok и semestr для метода `GetCurrentWeek` удается получить данные о текущей неделе(возвращается цифра недели). А вот при передаче параметров `potok`, `semestr`, `substance`(название группы, вводится кириллицей) для метода `RaspisForSubstance` ничего не выводится, хотя при передаче этих параметров в программе `SOAP UI` все выводится и показывает расписание. Вопрос, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://sfedu-tgn.ru/";
    private final String URL = "http://sfedu-tgn.ru/WebServices/Raspisanie.asmx?WSDL";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sfedu-tgn.ru/RaspisForSubstance";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "RaspisForSubstance";
    private static String val1, val2, val3;
    private static String result;
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et1, et2, et3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                val1 = et1.getText().toString();
                val2 = et2.getText().toString();
                val3 = et3.getText().toString();              

                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
            }
      });
}

    private class  AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        getRaspis(val1, val2, val3);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }

}

    public void getRaspis(String val1, String val2, String val3){
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo req1 = new PropertyInfo();
        req1.setName("potok");
        req1.setValue(val1.toString());

        PropertyInfo req2 = new PropertyInfo();
        req2.setName("semestr");
        req2.setValue(val2.toString());

        PropertyInfo req3 = new PropertyInfo();
        req3.setName("substance");
        req3.setValue(val3.toString());

        request.addProperty(req1);
        request.addProperty(req2);
        request.addProperty(req3);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            result = response.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте задать кодировку

```
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag="<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>"
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: возможно у вас ошибка в кодировке